# SQL SERVER - "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" to fully qualified domain name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi all my DBA has setup a primary `myNodeA` and secondary node `myNodeB` and I'm trying to access the secondary node using "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" in JDBC connection string.

The problem we are facing is it redirects to just a server name and not a fully qualified domain name.

is there a setting or configuration in SQL Server to achieve this?

For example using that parameter redirects to  `myNodeB`

This needs to redirect to `myNodeB.myDomain.com`

Comment: I think listener is the one which takes care of this redirecting,what ever you are interacting with is listener

Comment: Please post the same question on DBA.SE  with more details on sample server names and issue you are facing with redirects

Comment: @TheGameiswar Yes we use a listener name.  Do you have a link where you want me to post it?

Comment: @DocHoliday Please, post your question here https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks...posting now